# Warning not being sent to stderr

Tags: perl

I have a function that checks if data is valid (i.e. non-negative), and is supposed to warn then exit the sub.  The issue I am running into is that the warning is being suppressed.  Can anyone explain why the warning is being suppressed?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = b();
print "Function returned $a\n";

sub b
{
    my $a = -1;
    ($a >= 0) || (warn "\$a is negative" && return 0);
    print "Passed negative check\n";
    return 1;
}
```

The output that I receiving is

```
Function returned 0
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask to use a regular `if` here? Just because you can write it this way in Perl does not make it a good idea.

Comment: You can see exactly what's going on using `B::Deparse`: `perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub foo { (-1 >= 0) || (warn "foo" && return 0) } foo'` spits out `sub foo { warn return(0); } foo;`

Comment: Note that using lexicals `$a` and `$b` is considered bad form as it can mess with `sort` and similar functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Precedence issue.

```
warn "\$a is negative" && return 0
```

means

```
warn("\$a is negative" && return 0)
```

You want

```
warn "\$a is negative" and return 0
```

or

```
warn("\$a is negative") && return 0
```

Better yet, apply both changes.

```
warn("\$a is negative") and return 0
```

Be wary of pitfalls when you omit parens around argument lists.

Generally, use `and` and `or` if the RHS expression consists of a flow-control expression such as `die`, `return`, `next`, `last`, `redo` or `exit`.

---

Actually, why are you checking what `warn` returns? You actually want

```
warn("\$a is negative"), return 0
```

or

```
do { warn "\$a is negative"; return 0 }
```

---

So we get

```
$a >= 0
   or warn("\$a is negative"), return 0;
```

or

```
$a >= 0
   or do {
      warn "\$a is negative";
      return 0;
   };
```

But I suspect most people would prefer seeing

```
if ($a < 0) {
   warn "\$a is negative";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wish I could give a 2nd point just for the "Actually, why are you checking what `warn` returns?"